# Search Keyword Tracking

Tags: 2007, search

i have a public facing internet site with search enabled on it and i have page with the SearchCoreResults Webpart. I need to get a track of keywords which the users have keyed in the search box. Is there any way to accomplish this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use search query logging?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262541%28office.12%29.aspx

1. On the SSP home page, in the Office SharePoint Usage Reporting section, click Usage reporting.
2. On the Configure Advanced Usage Analysis Processing page, in the Processing Settings section, click Enable advanced usage analysis processing.
3. **In the Search Query Logging section, select Enable search query logging.**
4. Click OK.

Comment: That worked like a charm